# Selecting value of a dropdown select in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using session variables to pass values from one page to another in php. I have passed a value from one page to another, now I want the passed value to be selected in dropdown menu.

Suppose dropdown select has 1,2,3,4,5 and when I pass 2 to the page containing dropdown, 2 should automatically get selected. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will loop $x to 5 and check on each one if Session value is equal to it's value and then select it for you.

```
 <select name="numbers" id="numbers" >
    <?php for ($x=1; $x < 5; $x++): ?>
        <option <?php if($_SESSION['value'] ==$x){echo "selected";} ?> value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x;></option>
    <?php end for ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select> 
       <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['your-session'] == 1) ? "selected" : "" ?> value='1'>1</option>
       <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['your-session'] == 2) ? "selected" : "" ?> value='2'>2</option>
       <option <?php echo ($_SESSION['your-session'] == 3) ? "selected" : "" ?> value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

printing  "selected" on the option tag will solve your problem, you must check first if the value of the option is the value you stored in your session.

Comment: Good answers are explained. What you have is a code dump that says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly something like this should work, but for future reference please show more effort in your question i.e posting your code or some research attempts.

```
  <label for ="Numbers"><span>Numbers</span>
    <select name="numbers" id="numbers" >

        <option value="" <?php if($_SESSION['value'] ==""){echo "selected";} ?>>Please Select</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($_SESSION['value'] =="1"){echo "selected";} ?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($_SESSION['value'] =="2"){echo "selected";} ?>>2</option>

    </select>
    </label>
```